# Linking error when use Python embedding code on C++ code (Tensorflow with CUDA)

Tags: c++, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have installed a tensorflow wheel with GPU support on jetson TX2 (recommended by NVIDIA . So tensorflow is installed in

> /.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow

Also the ldd of the tensorflow libs seems to be perfect.

> ldd libtensorflow_framework.so
>           linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x0000007f89736000)
>           libcublas.so.9.0 => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libcublas.so.9.0 (0x0000007f86c56000)
>           libcuda.so.1 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libcuda.so.1 (0x0000007f86275000)
>           libcudnn.so.7 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so.7 (0x0000007f77bcb000)
>           libcufft.so.9.0 => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libcufft.so.9.0 (0x0000007f70af0000)
>           libcurand.so.9.0 => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libcurand.so.9.0 (0x0000007f6cab3000)
>           libcudart.so.9.0 => /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/libcudart.so.9.0 (0x0000007f6ca4e000)
>           libdl.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x0000007f6ca3a000)
>           libm.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x0000007f6c98d000)
>           libpthread.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000007f6c961000)
>           libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000007f6c7d1000)
>           libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000007f6c7b0000)
>           libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000007f6c669000)
>           /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000005562b57000)
>           librt.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x0000007f6c651000)
>           libnvrm_gpu.so => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libnvrm_gpu.so (0x0000007f6c61c000)
>           libnvrm.so => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libnvrm.so (0x0000007f6c5e4000)
>           libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.28.2.1 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.28.2.1 (0x0000007f6c57e000)
>           libnvos.so => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/tegra/libnvos.so (0x0000007f6c561000)

Then I have Jupyter notebooks working and also I can import tensorflow from a python3 console, but I want to embed the tensorflow code inside a C++ project.

I'm using the python embedding code like this.

```
Py_Initialize();

//Import
PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
PyRun_SimpleString("import tensorflow as tf");
```

This throws this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcusolver.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'tf' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'tf_config' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'tf' is not defined
```

The tensorflow version is 11 so is compatible with cuda 9.0. but I don't know why embeded code can not find the cuda libraries.